# Find string then set it as variable

Tags: variables, batch-file

Im working on a big batch project that requires a password from a from a text file with FINDSTR.

```
@echo off
title Login Service 
CD c:\
findstr "}--Account1--{ Password" }Properties{.txt
SET ::outcome of findstr
```

#### NOTE

`}--Account1--{`
`//Account1 Name = Joe Password = Any`
`}--Account2--{`
`//Account2 Name = Password =`
`}--Defaults--{`
`ConsoleColor =`
That's what }Properties{.txt looks like.
So if I do 
`findstr "}--Account1--{ Password" }Properties{.txt` then I get

> //Account1 Name = Joe Password = Any
>
> //Account2 Name = Password =

Idealy, I would like a way to make findstr only display the first line of string, to prevent errors.

#### END OF NOTE

Im stuck there.

So, Can I set a variable from the input of FINDSTR?
NOTE: I want the variable to only contain string after the `=`, or in Account1 just `ANY`

Thank you for your time and co-operation.

:)

Comment: What's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I tried. It may give you some ideas...

My input file test.txt contains:

```
user=hello password=world
user=me password=you
user= password=
```

The batch file is:

```
@echo off
findstr "user" test.txt > tmp.txt
set /p out1=<tmp.txt
for /f "tokens=3 delims=^=" %%a in ("%out1%") do (
  set v=%%a
) 
echo %v%
```

According to my tests, it displays`world` as the content of variable `v`.